# Aggregate function and other columns

Tags: sql, aggregate

Is it possible for a SQL query to return some normal columns and some aggregate ones?

like :

```
Col_A | Col_B | SUM
------+-------+------
   5  |   6   |  7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the [group by statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

> The GROUP BY statement is used in
>   conjunction with the aggregate
>   functions to group the result-set by
>   one or more columns.

For example:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
```

You can see a complete example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course. Read on GROUP BY and aggregate functions. e.g.

```
SELECT col1, col2, SUM(col3) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add them to GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you GROUP BY some fields, you can show those fields, and aggregate others; e.g.:

```
SELECT colA, colB, SUM(colC)
FROM TheTable
GROUP BY colA, colB
```

aggregation can be by SUM, MIN, MAX, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can show ordinary columns or expressions based on ordinary columns, but only if they are included in the set of columns/expressions you are agregating over ( what is listed in Group By clause ).