# Normal columns followed with agregate functions but not in group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I knew that normal columns followed by aggregate functions are allowed only if a `Group By` including them follows.
But then why is the following working?

```
mysql> select payee,sum(amount) from checks;  
+---------+-------------+  
| payee   | sum(amount) |  
+---------+-------------+  
| Ma Bell |      893.76 |  
+---------+-------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I don't know WHY it's not illegal - but it should be, as the result returned by the non aggregated column is a random row's value, and being able to do it will be confusing to people who don't expect the result.

Comment: @Patashu:I was expecting an error.Could not understand why I didn't get one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This behavior is an "extension" to MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html):

> MySQL extends the use of `GROUP BY` so that the select list can refer
>   to nonaggregated columns not named in the `GROUP BY` clause.

However, [This behavior is actually a configurable setting in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by):

> `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`
>
> Do not permit queries for which the select list or (as of MySQL
>   5.1.10) HAVING list refers to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause.

It is best to *respect* the `group by` and add all non-aggregated columns, especially if there's the possibility that you might someday migrate to a server that has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` turned on.

Comment: @njk it is a disservice to people learning SQL if it is not enabled.  Especially if they move to another system

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT** Manual reference which does a better job explaining than I do and note the details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

This is intended to work fine. Without an aggregate function it does it on all rows returned in the query. The reason you see little on this I think is that this is rarely what you are actually trying to accomplish. You frequently drop the group by when you have a where clause which you know would only return things from which you were planning to group by anyway. i.e. if you query is:

```
select payee,sum(amount) from checks where payee = 'Ma Bell'
```

The group by in the following is technically redundant:

```
select payee,sum(amount) from checks where payee = 'Ma Bell' group by payee
```

Personally - I typically include the GROUP BY clause as I *THINK* it is more consistently supported cross platform... not 100% sure of that though.

Again, in your query above I would again ask - even though it technically works, are you getting the result you are after without a where clause?

Comment: Are these answers inaccurate then?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249125/aggregate-function-and-other-columns

Comment: *Reference coming*.. [The suspense is killing me](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html).

Comment: :) Thanks for that - kept finding the aggregate function page